# "Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response" with only one touch container

Tags: javascript, android, css, android-webview, css-transitions

I have something like this:

```
<div class='hscroller'>
    <div class='carousel'><ul></ul></div>
</div>
```

`.hscroller` is a horizontal scrollable container (scroll via `transform3d` on touch Events)

`.carousel` is an horizontal scrollable image list (scroll via `transform3d` without any touch events)

Well, when I try to touch `.hscroller` I get the following error and I can’t scroll anymore:

```
W/webview (23193): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
```

I already have `e.preventDefault()` on `touchMove` and `touchStart` Events and of course if I `display:none` the carousel, everything works fine, even after the carousel made some transitions.

I know there are other issues with this error but i think this is a different use-case.

Any idea how can I can solve this?